# Save Excel as PDF using cell value as name - Run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to save an excel sheet as PDF on my desktop and use the delivery date as the file name for each pdf it saves, but I keep getting a Run-Time error. The error happens at "'Save the PDF file". Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
Sub ExportingPDF()

'Defining worksheets
Dim detailsSheet As Worksheet
Dim reportSheet As Worksheet

Set reportSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contract Form")
Set detailsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("New POs")

'Looping the through each row
For i = 2 To 16

'Assigning values
SPile = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 2)
SClient = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 3)
SCommodity = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 4)
SOption = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 5)
SQtyMT = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 6)
SWhs = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 8)
SDeliveryCity = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 10)
SPO = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 12)
SDeliveryDate = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 15)
SWhsAddress = detailsSheet.Cells(i, 18)



'Generating the output
reportSheet.Cells(19, 1).Value = SPile
reportSheet.Cells(11, 1).Value = SClient
reportSheet.Cells(19, 3).Value = SCommodity
reportSheet.Cells(19, 2).Value = SOption
reportSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = SWhs
reportSheet.Cells(12, 1).Value = SDeliveryCity
reportSheet.Cells(17, 1).Value = SPO
reportSheet.Cells(27, 3).Value = SDeliveryDate
reportSheet.Cells(5, 1).Value = SWhsAddress
reportSheet.Cells(22, 2).Value = SQtyMT

Error Happens here:
***'Save the PDF file
Worksheets("Contract Form").Range("A1:E28").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, 
Filename:= _
"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\" & SDeliveryDate, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False***

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Likely you need to `Format` the date so it doesn't contain illegal characters. Also you might consider concatenating the `".pdf"` extension.

Comment: Thank you BigBen - it worked! Now I realized I have another question. I would like the macro to run until the last line in the detailsheet. Right now I have it run from row 2 to 16 but only have 5 rows in there today so I just got a run-time error even though the first 5 rows were saved perfectly.

Comment: [How to find the last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba)